# Test Case Reporting in Selenium Webdriver script

Tags: html, pdf, selenium-webdriver, junit, report

What would be the best and simplest way to generate a report of you test cases in selenium webdriver script. I know about TestNG and would like to know options apart from TestNG. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Robot Framework, it generates a very comprehensive test report. Here is a sample. 
[image]

- There is lots more to it, if you click on "+" button to expand the report sub sections.

Comment: Check Extent Reports also.  Link. http://relevantcodes.com/extentreports-for-selenium/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a html report by yourself instead of another tools and get the runtime details even the screenshots, I suggest use log4j framwork. You can implement the key method by yourself.

You are able to rewrite [HTMLLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.java#HTMLLayout.0TRACE_PREFIX). Try implementing these two methods

- public String format()
- public String getHeader()

You can compose a report by you own style. Once you have performd a keyword such as click and input text, you just need to pass a message to Logger.info() or Logger.error().

BTW, Robot Framework is good as well. So dose Junit and [Fitnesse](http://www.fitnesse.org/).